# Strange drawing behavior of NSSegmentedControl, when superview is drawn

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, nsview, quartz-2d, nssegmentedcontrol

I've got a problem with the NSSegmentedControl.
I have a custom view where I draw a gradient with a shadow.
The drawing is ok, but when I place a NSSegmentedControl inside it then something strange happens - the background of the custom view is shining through the segmented control, as if the segmented control had a low alpha value.

Here are pictures, that demonstrate the issue :

With the custom view in background :
[image]

Without the custom view in background :
[image]

As you can see in the left upper corner in the first image the segmented control isn't drawing properly.
Here is the drawRect method from the custom view :

```
- (void)drawRect:(NSRect)dirtyRect {

    NSShadow *shadow = [[NSShadow alloc] init];

    [shadow setShadowOffset:NSMakeSize(0.0, -6.0)];

    [shadow setShadowBlurRadius:3.0];

    [shadow setShadowColor:[[NSColor blackColor] colorWithAlphaComponent:0.3]];

    [shadow set];



    NSGradient *gradient = [[NSGradient alloc] initWithColorsAndLocations:[NSColor colorWithDeviceWhite:0.8 alpha:1.0],(CGFloat)0.0,[NSColor colorWithDeviceWhite:0.65 alpha:1.0],(CGFloat)0.5,[NSColor colorWithDeviceWhite:0.3 alpha:1.0],(CGFloat)0.5,[NSColor colorWithDeviceWhite:0.5 alpha:1.0],(CGFloat)1.0, nil];

    [gradient drawInRect:self.bounds angle:90];



    NSBezierPath *bezierPath = [NSBezierPath bezierPath];

    [bezierPath moveToPoint:NSMakePoint(0, 0)];

    [bezierPath lineToPoint:NSMakePoint(-self.bounds.size.height, 0)];

    [bezierPath lineToPoint:NSMakePoint(-self.bounds.size.height, -self.bounds.size.width)];

    [bezierPath lineToPoint:NSMakePoint(0, -self.bounds.size.width)];



    [[NSColor whiteColor] set];



    [bezierPath stroke];

}
```

Can you help me with this?
I don't know how to fix this issue.

Comment: The All | Gro... | Fav... control? I can't understand what the problem is.

Comment: I'm sorry. I was a little bit unprecise. I mean the forward-backward segmented control - It shouldn't have this ugly gradient in the first picture.

Comment: So you're asking – why does the gradient you're applying to the toolbar bleed into the back–forward and + buttons?

Answer (score 1):

I don't know if you're doing any custom drawing in the toolbar buttons, but I think your problem is that you're calling 'set' on the shadow without saving and restoring your graphics context.

Look at the documentation for NSShadow's set method.
[NSShadow Documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/ApplicationKit/Classes/NSShadow_Class/Reference/Reference.html)

> "The shadow attributes of the receiver are used until another shadow is
>   set or until the **graphics state is restored**."

You should always save your graphics context first, then call any of Cocoa's set-style methods, then restore the context. This keeps future draw commands from applying your shadow.

```
NSGraphicsContext *context = [NSGraphicsContext currentContext];
[context saveGraphicsState];

NSShadow *myCoolShadow = [NSShadow new];
// Shadow code here
[myCoolShadow set];

[context restoreGraphicsState];
```

Answer (score 1):

On 10.7+, Rounded Textured segmented controls and buttons are transparent. On 10.5-10.6, they are gradient filled.